# Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, google-closure

I am trying to use [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input) with rails application and i am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined (anonymous function)

from this thine of code

```
// includes
goog.require('i18n.phonenumbers.AsYouTypeFormatter');
goog.require('i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat');
goog.require('i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil');
```

Please tell how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest defining `goog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by:

adding

```
gem 'intl-tel-input-rails'
```

to my Gemfile